# what is best practice for handling sql indexes when rebuilding a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a stored procedure that is going to build a table overnight.

The first step is to truncate since I can't guarantee that existing records won't be updated, thus wiping and rebuilding is the easiest option.

What I'd like advice on is the best practice for the indexes.  Should I drop the index at the start and then build it afterwards?  Or is there a better method.  The table will have around 300k records in it, and 7 columns

Comment: There is another question with similar scenario. Refer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983979/insertion-of-data-after-creating-index-on-empty-table-or-creating-unique-index-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tests which may help you :

```
test1:
1.truncate table and don't delete indexes
2.insert data and check speed
3.check fragmentation

test2:
1.Truncate table
2.insert data and check speed
3.create indexes and check fragmentation


test1:
--insert data and check speed

delcare @id int=0
select current_timestamp;

while(@id<=1000000)
begin

insert into indextest
select @id,newid(),case when @id%10=0 then 1 else @id end;

set @id=@id+1
end

select current_timestamp;


--check fragmentation
--now check fragmentation
SELECT object_id, index_id, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(‘AdventureWorks2016’), OBJECT_ID(‘indextest’), NULL, NULL, NULL);


test2:
----truncate table
truncate table indextest

--drop indexes
drop index idx_id on indextest;
drop index nci_idx  on indextest;


---now insert data
delcare @id int=0
select current_timestamp;

while(@id<=1000000)
begin

insert into indextest
select @id,newid(),case when @id%10=0 then 1 else @id end;

set @id=@id+1
end

select current_timestamp;

--create index
create clustered index idx_id on indextest(id);

create non clustered index nci_idx on indextest(addres);

---check fragmentation:
SELECT object_id, index_id, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(‘AdventureWorks2016’), OBJECT_ID(‘indextest’), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

**Summary:**
When indexes are already existing

**inserting data took** 3:23 seconds  and Fragmentation after insert
[image]

When we drop and recreate indexes after data load:

**insert speed:**2:44 seconds

**fragmentation:**
[image]

That said ,my test depends on optimal log growth settings,disk speed.Further you may not worry much about fragmentation ,fragmentation only affects you only for range scans.I recommend dropping and recreating indexes based on your table usage.