# How to get a list of tables that need tuning

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a database with tables that grow every day. I cannot predict which tables are going to grow and which are not as I'm not the one who is putting the data into them.

Is there a way to find tables that need indexes at a particular point in time? Is there a way, in SQL Server, to notify me if a database needs tuning on certain tables?

This is a product we have deployed at different client locations and we cannot go onto their servers every time to check if they have a performance issue. What I was thinking about is something that can notify me if there are performance issues on certain tables, so as the new patches go to the clients we can add these indexes or tuned queries.

After referring to [Insertion of data after creating index on empty table or creating unique index after inserting data on oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983979/insertion-of-data-after-creating-index-on-empty-table-or-creating-unique-index-a) I'm not willing to create indexes while installing databases or when the tables have few rows or are empty.

Comment: Create indexes on empty tables -- whoever told you that was full of carp.

Comment: How large are these tables?  A primary key constraint will create an index automatically on the key column.  I wouldn't worry about indexing an empty table.  I can't see how that would negatively impact anything.  Query optimizer takes statistics about how you use certain tables and does a lot of stuff automatically.  Could you be more specific to what you're looking to accomplish besides indexing correctly?

Comment: Millions of rows are there 30 columns approx. Hogan I want answers instead of some other talks sorry to say that.

Comment: One tool that I use quite frequently and is very helpful, [`sp_BlitzIndex`](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/).

Comment: You have no insight into what data you have? If there is no business sense, how can you adequately index your tables? As for scalability, surely there are ways to track at least the size of tables, use or otherwise. Sounds like a mix of Q&A and report writing would help you. Because throwing indexes on tables because they "must" have one is stupid.

Comment: @JohnVM - I gave you an answer.  Create the indexes as soon as you understand the business need.  If you don't know the needs or expections find them out, then create the indexes.  You question was **"When do I create indexes."**  I give you an answer... **"Yesterday."**

Comment: Please read my requirment. What i want is something to notify me from the client location that few tables are performing slow and it needs tuning.

Comment: then look for slow queries and either work out what indexes are missing how how their indexes should be written better

Comment: This is a product and you have deployed it at different client locations and you just cannot go onto there servers every time to check if they have a performance issue so what i was thinking is about something which can notify me that there are performance issues on certain tables and it requires tuning so as the new patches go to client sides we can add these indexes or tuned queries to respective clients.  Some body -1 ed the question without adding a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding we must not create indexes on a smaller table as it can affect the write performances.

This is only a real concern if you're bulk loading or otherwise generating a hundred million records each day and write performance is a problem.  Indexes do increase write times because they have to be updated when data is written, but unless you're running on a potato or running very high loads it's unlikely to be a problem.  You'd know it was a problem before you encountered it.

If we're talking about small tables (less than 100 pages) then it's much more likely that indexes won't be useful because the data set is so small, but you shouldn't be concerned about impacting write performance.

Overall, your application should have indexes that support the queries that you expect should be run in your unit testing and staging.  You will need feedback from your customers or clients, but until you really know how people use their data, you're going to have to make a best guess.

---

The general question of "How do I know what indexes I need when I don't know what queries will be run?" is better suited to [DBA Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com).  Briefly, you'll need to use dynamic management views for that.  The three [missing index dynamic views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345364.aspx) can be used for this.  The example query given isn't horrible:

```
SELECT mig.*, statement AS table_name,  
    column_id, column_name, column_usage  
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_missing_index_columns (mid.index_handle)  
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig 
    ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle  
ORDER BY mig.index_group_handle, mig.index_handle, column_id;
```

You shouldn't just blindly follow what this view says, however.  It's a good lead on what to look at, but you have to look at the column order and queries actually being used to tell.

You should also monitor [index usage statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) and examine how much and in what way indexes are used compared to how much they have to be updated.  Indexes that are updated a million times a day but are used once or twice should be considered for removal.

You will also want to monitor [query stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) to look for queries that run for a long time.  This may be poor development on the part of your client, but can also be a sign of design problems.

This is not even a comprehensive *overview* of things to look for, however.  There's a lot to database maintenance and operations.  That's why DBAs make a good living.  This is just the tip of the iceberg.  Just the tip for indexes, even.

What I'd do if you want to maintain this is consider asking your customers to allow you to send feedback for performance analysis.  Set up a broker that monitors the management views and sends compiled and sanitized information back to yourselves.  You'll need to be very careful about what you send because you don't want to be sending actual customer data, of course.

Keep in mind that dynamic management views typically reset when the instance does, so the results will not typically represent the entire lifespan of the database.